# Terms aggregation performance high cardinality

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, cardinality

I'm hoping for some clarifications for query performance in elastic 1.5.2 I observed recently.

I have a string field with high cardinality (approx 200,000,000).
I observed that if I use a simple terms aggregation with execution hint global_ordinals_low_cardinality, two things happen:
1. The query returns same results as with global_ordinals, or global_ordinals_hash.
2. The query performs significantly faster. (about twice as fast as global_ordinals, and 4 times as fast as global_ordinals_hash.

Here's the query:

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "myTerms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "myField",
            "size": 1000,
            "shard_size": 1000,
            "execution_hint": "global_ordinals_low_cardinality"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I don't understand why its even legitimate to use global_ordinals_low_cardinality in this instance, because my field has a high cardinality. So perhaps I don't understand what exactly global_ordinals_low_cardinality means?

Secondly, I have another numerical field (long), with roughly same cardinality value.
The values of the long field are actually precomputed hash values (murmur3) for the same string field from above, which i use to greatly speedup cardinality aggregation.
Running the same terms aggregation on the numerical field performs as bad as global_ordinals_hash.
In fact, it doesn't matter what execution hint i use, execution time remains the same.

So why is global_ordinals_low_cardinality applicable for string types, but not for long types? Is it because numerical fields do not require global ordinals at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think both the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-execution-hint) and the source code shed some light on this. First off, one thing that needs to be mentioned is that `execution_hint` is exactly what its name says, i.e. **just an hint** that ES will try to honor, but might not in all cases if it deems not appropriate.

So, the mere fact that you have a high cardinality field precludes the use of `global_ordinals_low_cardinality` since:

> `global_ordinals_low_cardinality` is only enabled by default on low-cardinality fields.

As for `global_ordinals_hash`, it is mainly used in inner terms aggregations (not the case here), and `map` is only used when running an aggregation on scripts and few documents match the query (not the cas either)

So it leaves you with one choice, i.e. `global_ordinals` which is the default hint used on top-level terms aggregations.

As mentioned earlier, `execution_hint` is just an hint you specify, but ES will try its best to pick the right execution mode for your data no matter what. Looking into the source code is enlightening and sheds some light on a few things:

[Starting here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/90f32d4d32cde5ae28fbc6a3e725afafbdf1c58f/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/TermsAggregatorFactory.java#L198), you'll see that:

1. [on line 201](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/90f32d4d32cde5ae28fbc6a3e725afafbdf1c58f/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/TermsAggregatorFactory.java#L201), your hint is read, and then might get overridden if the field doesn't support global ordinals ([lines 205-241](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/90f32d4d32cde5ae28fbc6a3e725afafbdf1c58f/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/TermsAggregatorFactory.java#L205-L241))
2. if your [field is numeric](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/90f32d4d32cde5ae28fbc6a3e725afafbdf1c58f/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/terms/TermsAggregatorFactory.java#L255-L271), `execution_hint` is completely ignored, and this should probably answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response Val. I'm aware that execution_hint might be overridden, but I must remind you that the query performs ***significantly*** better with global_ordinals_low_cardinality, so I don't think it was ignored. Secondly, I would also like to know, why is it possible for a terms aggregation on a high cardinality string field, to perform much better than a terms aggregation on its long hash counterpart, which doesn't even require global ordinals at all...?

Comment: If you look at my second point, I said the hint is only ignored for your `long` field, which answers your second question. If you do specify a hint, of course it is taken blindly into account by ES (except when the field doesn't support ordinals). As for why `global_ordinals_low_cardinality` performs much better than its counterparts, [this pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/5895) might shed some light.

Comment: I got an answer to the second part of my question here:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/terms-aggregation-performance-high-cardinality/26639/3

However, it is still not exactly clear for me why global_ordinals_low_cardinality works better even on high cardinality fields.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. As jpountz said, global_ordinals_low_cardinality is the fastest execution mode, but comes with a toll on the memory.  Maybe you have enough memory available so it doesn't make any difference in the end and you don't notice anything.

Comment: Maybe i do have enough memory, however i would expect to see increased heap usage, which i don't. However, i can't say with great confidence that I tested the last statement thoroughly, so i'll do some tests next week, and update accordingly.